# Pageshow loads Google maps only the first time

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

the question is very easy; if I show the page "map1", the google map is loaded only one time. In my web application I changed the value of latitute e longitude, but the map showed is ever the first. Why don't loads a new position every time?

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#map1', function () {

    var lat = (localStorage.getItem('lat'));
    var lng = (localStorage.getItem('lng'));

    console.log(lat + ',' + lng);
    alert("!");

    $('#map_canvas2').gmap({
        'center': '' + lat_det + ',' + lng_det + '',
        'zoom': 10,
        'disableDefaultUI': true,
        'callback': function () {
            var self = this;
            self.addMarker({
                'position': this.get('map').getCenter()
            }).click(function () {
                self.openInfoWindow({
                    'content': 'Position'
                }, this);
            });
        }
    });

    map_element2 = document.getElementById("map_canvas2");

    var mapwidth2 = $(window).width();
    var mapheight2 = $(window).height();
    $("#map_canvas2").height(mapheight2);
    $("#map_canvas2").width(mapwidth2);

    google.maps.event.trigger(map_element2, 'resize');

});
```

Comment: I try with $.mobile.changePage but the behavior is the same.

$('a.force-reload').live('click', function(e) {
 var url = $(this).attr('href');
 $.mobile.changePage( url, { reloadPage: true, transition: "none"} );
});

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you are doing it in a wrong way.

Your map is created first time pageshow event is triggered and it will stay there unless you remove it manually or change current marker position.

There are 2 possible solutions to this problem.

### Solution 1

On map pagehide event remove current map

```
$(document).on('pagehide', '#map1', function () {
    $.mobile.activePage.find('#map_canvas2').empty();
});
```

It will be recreated next time you vidit your page.

### Solution 2

Less invasive solution would be to save your marker as a global variable and change it (if it exist if not create a new one) like this:

```
function changeMarkerPosition(marker) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-24.397, 140.644);
    marker.setPosition(latlng);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gajotres, there is a problem that I don't understand.
If I use your solution1, at the next loading of the page "map1", i saw the alert but the script don't reload the map. That's incredible.

Comment: why: $(document).on('pagehide', '#map1', function () {
    $.mobile.activePage.find('#map_canvas2').empty();
}); don't change the page "map1" cache??

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i solved it issues loading map on a externale page by:

```
<a href="map.html" rel="external" data-ajax="false" >
```

In this modality the code work perfectly.

Hope this help somebody.